# Laravel collection: split based on criteria (trackpoints where there a long pause)

Tags: laravel, laravel-collection

What I am trying to achieve:
1) get the trackpoints in a points array where the time difference with the previous trackpoint in that points array is too big
2) add new (copy of the previous) segment, and put these trackpoints in that segment

Quite sure the [Laravel collection methods](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/collections) can be super helpful, just not sure how to achieve it in a clean way. Clever plain PHP is fine as well of course.

Example:

```
        $example = collect([
            "tracks" => [
                [
                    "name" => "track 1",
                    "segments" => [
                        [
                            "name" => "track 1 - segment 1",
                            "points" => [
                                ["timestamp" => "2008-09-21T11:00:10Z", "lat"=>1, "lon"=>1],
                                ["timestamp" => "2008-09-21T11:00:20Z", "lat"=>1, "lon"=>1],
                                ["timestamp" => "2008-09-21T11:00:30Z", "lat"=>1, "lon"=>1],
                                ["timestamp" => "2008-09-21T11:00:40Z", "lat"=>1, "lon"=>1],
                                // --- split here ("clone" 'track 1 - segment 1' between segment 1 and 2)
                                ["timestamp" => "2008-09-21T13:00:10Z", "lat"=>1, "lon"=>1],
                                ["timestamp" => "2008-09-21T13:00:20Z", "lat"=>1, "lon"=>1],
                                ["timestamp" => "2008-09-21T13:00:30Z", "lat"=>1, "lon"=>1],
                                // --- and split here
                                ["timestamp" => "2008-09-21T15:00:10Z", "lat"=>1, "lon"=>1],
                                ["timestamp" => "2008-09-21T15:00:20Z", "lat"=>1, "lon"=>1],
                            ]
                        ],
                        [
                            "name" => "track 1 - segment 2",
                            "points" => []
                        ],
                    ],  
                ],
                [
                    "name" => "track 2",
                    "segments" => []
                ]
            ]
        ]);
```

Edit: example of "too big" = diff of two timestamps is bigger than 30 seconds.

Comment: What do you mean too big?

Comment: How to you classify a `too big difference with the previous trackpoint`?

Comment: Example of too big: "if diff of two timestamps is bigger than 30 seconds"